# All oData Web APIs are broken after importing solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

using Dynamics CRM 2016 on premises, after importing an unmanaged solution in an organization (via the Web API Action ImportSolution and then PublishAllXml), all the Web APIs have stopped working, and return the following :

(example : https://MyDynamicsServer/MyOrganization/api/data/v8.0/contacts )

```
{
  "Message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
  "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.OData.Edm.ExtensionMethods.AddAlternateKeyAnnotation(EdmModel model, IEdmEntityType type, IDictionary`2 alternateKey)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataModelProvider.DeclareAlternateKeys(EdmEntityType entityType, EntityMetadata entityMetadata, EdmModel edmModel)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataModelProvider.AddEntitiesToModel(ICollection`1 edmEntitySets, EdmModel model, EdmEntityContainer container)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataModelProvider.AddEntities(Dictionary`2 edmModels, Dictionary`2 containers, DynamicMetadataCache cache)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataModelProvider.InitializeEdmModels(DynamicMetadataCache cache)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataModelProvider.GetEdmModel(ModelVisibility requestedEdmType)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmEdmModel.get_InternalEdmModel()\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmEdmModel.get_EntityContainer()\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Edm.ExtensionMethods.FindDeclaredEntitySet(IEdmModel model, String qualifiedName)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Edm.ExtensionMethods.FindDeclaredNavigationSource(IEdmModel model, String qualifiedName)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathParser.TryCreateSegmentForNavigationSource(String identifier, String parenthesisExpression)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathParser.CreateFirstSegment(String segmentText)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathParser.ParsePath(ICollection`1 segments)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.ODataPathFactory.BindPath(ICollection`1 segments, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataUriParser.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel model, String serviceRoot, String odataPath, ODataUriResolverSetttings resolverSettings, Boolean enableUriTemplateParsing)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel model, String serviceRoot, String odataPath)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel model, String serviceRoot, String odataPath)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, String parameterName, IDictionary`2 values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraint(HttpRequestMessage request, Object constraint, String parameterName, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraints(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)",
  "ErrorCode": 500
}
```

This is critical, as it makes our customizations unusable !  (and also prevents us from importing customizations automatically, as this process uses Web API)

Note that the same solution has been imported in another organization the same way without issue ...

The import of the solution through the UI still works, but that completely defeats the point of our automation pipeline ...

Has anyone encountered this issue ? Where should I look ?

(note : I have also posted this question here : https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/206996 )

Comment: You may want to open a support ticket with MSFT for this one

Comment: Agree with Matt Dearing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your OData is not enabled or not supported. Please check via

```
Settings => Customizations => Developer Resources
```